# Why does geth use so much bandwidth in light mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, light-clients

So I am running latest geth 1.8 (same thing happens with geth 1.7) and I have noticed that I am always downloading at about 2 megabytes / sec and uploading 120 kilobytes / sec. This is caused by geth process.

```
/home/user/.config/Ethereum Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked/geth --syncmode light --cache 1024
```

I thought light mode will same me both disk space and bandwidth. What is the reasoning for SO MUCH DATA being downloaded constantly to my PC? I dont see how this can be justified since I am not supposed to be downloading whole blockchain.